# pip3 list comes AssertionError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

when I do `pip3 list` in the terminal, it comes the following error:

```
cliu@cliu-ubuntu:~$ pip3 list
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 80, in run
    self.run_listing(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 142, in run_listing
    self.output_package_listing(installed_packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 151, in output_package_listing
    if dist_is_editable(dist):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 367, in dist_is_editable
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 299, in from_dist
    assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
AssertionError

Storing debug log for failure in /home/cliu/.pip/pip.log
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Nice. You might be interested to have a look at this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1445947

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to modify this code

Comment: where is `pip/__init__.py` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the bug linked in the comments, this can be fixed by upgrading to the latest Pip.  Since doing that within Ubuntu/Debian's packaging system is moderately nontrivial, I think it would probably be simpler to just install a new version of Pip into a [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).  Once you've created the virtualenv, you can upgrade to the latest Pip with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Multiple things come to mind: 1. "Not working" doesn't mean anything.  What error message did you get?  2. If you're in a virtualenv (you are, right?), it's just called "pip", no need for the 3.  3. Even if you're not in a virtualenv, pip calls itself "pip", so it would be `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.  But outside a virtualenv, that won't work without sudo and would probably confuse APT, so I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Though there is an accepted answer here, that did not work for me. So, my answer might help others who face the same issue. 
This bug was fixed with a single line commit here.

https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/6cab71f422f2425b4d2283023c9e955f9663dde6

The solution is to change the line from

```
assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
```

to

```
assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] in ["==", "==="]
```

The line number varies from version to version but, the debug message should make it easier to find. In your case it is `line 299`, in the file `"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py"`

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I have had the same problem, but the first solution didn't work for me(I was getting the same error after purging it over again and over again). So I have decided to edit the the line.

```
assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
```

And removed:

```
 == '=='
```

Funny, but it works now.

Comment: Why the down vote? It worked perfectly for me back then.
That's just not fair. Since my answer was the first one touching the matter. Look at the answered date.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by commenting out the problematic `assert` statement:

```
# assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
```

This is definitely not an ideal solution, as that statement is probably there for a good reason, but `pip3 list` now works, as do all the other parts of pip3 that I use.